# How can I load dynamically my AngularJS application dependencies

Tags: angularjs

Let's say, I have HTML like this

```
<html ng-app='CoreAngular_App'>
<script>
    var CoreAngular_AppObj = angular.module('CoreAngular_App', ['importantModule1', 'importantModule2', 'customModule1', 'customModule2', 'customModule3']);
</script>
<!-- here goes html structure with lot of ng-controller -->
<script>
    //controller example
    CoreAngular_AppObj.controller('MyControllerX', function($scope, myCustomModule2) {
    }
</script>
</html>
```

It works, but as I have a lot of controllers and I don't know which of them will used, I want to load this list `['customModule1', 'customModule2', 'customModule3']` dynamically

I will glad to get something like this.

```
<html ng-app='CoreAngular_App'>
<script>
    var CoreAngular_AppObj = angular.module('CoreAngular_App', ['importantModule1', 'importantModule2']);
</script>
<!-- here goes html structure with lot of ng-controller -->
<script>
    // ADD myCustomModule2 TO CoreAngular_AppObj HERE
    //controller example
    CoreAngular_AppObj.controller('MyControllerX', function($scope, myCustomModule2) {
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Is it possible? And how?

Thanks

Comment: Are you rendering the html, could you put it in the page?

Comment: @Dylan My original source rendered HTML is too huge, what part of that html you interested in. 
And I just need to know can I load my app dependencies dynamically. How it depends on rendered HTML?

Comment: I was just wondering if your dynamic controls were related to the backend (PHP, nodejs) etc.  Because you are injecting into your main module on page load.  The only way to precede that will probably be angular.bootstrap.

Comment: Some of my controllers use $http to get data from server

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to make an example of what either may look like.

**Inline - from backend logic** -

```
// Create list from rendered array.
var modules = ['customModule1', 'customModule3'];  // ex: print json_encode($arrayStr);
// Add a custom module
angular.module('myCustom', modules);

//Inject the custom module
angular.module('CoreApp', ['importantModule1', 'importantModule2', 'myCustom']);
```

---

**angular.bootstrap** [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)

Remember to remove `ng-app`

```
var app = angular.module('CoreApp', []);

someReadyFunction(){
    // figure out which moules here 
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['CoreApp', 'customModule1', 'customModule3']);
}
```